# JSON and escaped double quote

Tags: apex, json, string

I'm currently making a callout to a 3rd party vendor and I'm getting a huge response. What is currently messing me up is this section:

```
 "MessageSeq":13,"Description":"config file: config-qa1.txt\"","MessageTS":"2014-02-17T14:46:58","MessageLevel":4,"IsSystemMessage":false
```

As you can see here, the portion at the end of the Description value is ended with backslash double quote. If I attempt to parse this via the JSONParser I get an exception. Does anyone have an recommendations on how to resolve this?

*Exception Message:*

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:3699]

*Updated with sample Code*

```java
public class ResponseWrapper{
    // fields from JSON to auto map
    public Integer messageSeq;
    public String Description;
    public String messageTS;
    public Integer messageLevel;
    public Boolean isSystemMessage;
    // parsing fields
    private ResponseWrapper theResponse;
    private JSONParser parser;
    
    public void parse(String jsonString){
        parser = JSON.createParser(jsonString);
        parseJSON();
    }
    
    private void parseJSON(){   
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                theResponse = (ResponseWrapper)parser.readValueAs(ResponseWrapper.class);               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
String responseString = '{"MessageSeq":13,"Description":"config file: config-qa1.txt\"","MessageTS":"2014-02-17T14:46:58","MessageLevel":4,"IsSystemMessage":false}';
system.debug('\n\nBEFORE\n' + responseString);
//****Place code in here to test such as ReplaceALL***
ResponseWrapper parser = new ResponseWrapper();
parser.parse(responseString);
```

Comment: This is syntactically correct and validates at http://jsonlint.com/ What exception are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is caused by the \" ?  including the exception message in your question may help.

Comment: 16:36:15.863 (863767000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:3699]

Pretty much the string looks like such to the system and it fails to parse at that point.

"config file: config-qa1.txt"","MessageTS"

Comment: Exception included

Comment: If you are using Apex to parse, have a look at http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ .. Your posted example parses fine, but removing the escape character duplicates your error.  Maybe try double escaping ??

Comment: something like \\\"

Comment: Already tried this too. Still have issues. Let me code up something simple for you all to test this on

Comment: added sample code which throws same error, I'm testing this on eclipse currently

Comment: added sample code which throws same error, I'm testing this on eclipse currently

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It sounds like your exception is encountered not by the response, but by Apex code mimicking it?**

The response format is correct: the backslash `\` is correctly placed to permit a `"` in the JSON.

Check it out, if I put your string, literally, as plaintext into something returnable by an Apex function:

```
<apex:page contentType="text/plain">{"MessageSeq":13,"Description":"config file: config-qa1.txt\"","MessageTS":"2014-02-17T14:46:58","MessageLevel":4,"IsSystemMessage":false}</apex:page>
```

And then obtain that string in Apex:

```
String data = Page.MyTestPage.getContent().toString();
Map<String,Object> obj = (Map<String,Object>)Json.deserializeUntyped(data);
System.debug(obj);
```

he will deserialize just fine!

But if you intend to recreate that string in Apex source code, say in a test method, as a `WebServiceMock` or `HttpCalloutMock` you **must** escape the backslash itself in *Apex*:

```
String data = '{"MessageSeq":13,"Description":"config file: config-qa1.txt\\"","MessageTS":"2014-02-17T14:46:58","MessageLevel":4,"IsSystemMessage":false}';
//see double backslash here_______________________________________________^
```

Comment: exactly! added sample code which throws same error, I'm testing this on eclipse currently

Comment: @user320 This is a perfectly normal situation. Every known language that uses backslash to escape characters in a string, and does not have a "bare string" syntax suffers from this. For example, in C#, to reference a file on a windows server, you might write `\\\\Server\\Path\\Filename.ext`, which translates to `\\Server\Path\Filename.ext`. Notable exceptions include (I believe) scripting languages, like Perl, Ruby, and PHP. Some languages also offer a "anti-escape" operator, like C#'s @ symbol (assuming I'm not mixing up my syntaxes...)

Comment: So what would be the recommendation you have for me to resolve this issue? I'm unsure how I'm going to get that slash in there as I don't generate the response when I make the callout. I provided an example from the callout which was causing an issue.

Comment: @DoubleA I think your code `String responseString` is not representative of the actual response. The callout response, as received, parses as expected. But when it is hand-imitated as a string without escaping the backslash ``\\`` it becomes a different string. Pardon, I am struggling to explain :-) one backslash is already in the response, it should remain there, and you don't need to add anything.

Comment: @user320 yes, but if you run the sample code you will get the exception i'm currently getting. the section I provided as a string is a collection of that same object which gives backend information such as malformed parameters, exceptions, timeouts, errors, etc. I just pulled this section out of the response which is causing me this issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue using dphil's idea, then '\\\"' (3 slashes) might work in the replace statement. However, your original problem is still odd.

Comment: already attempted this  too

Comment: added sample code which throws same error, I'm testing this on eclipse currently

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that belongs there.... Maybe you should just parse it out before using the JSONParser?

```
jsonString = jsonString.replace('\\"', '');
```

Comment: Does not work. This will only remove all double quotes. You can test this out via developer console. If you debug your line before and after you'll see the ending result

Comment: What I had was

`String response = ' "MessageSeq":13,"Description":"config file: config-qa1.txt\"","MessageTS":"2014-02-17T14:46:58","MessageLevel":4,"IsSystemMessage":false';

system.debug('\n\nBEFORE\n' + response);

system.debug('\n\nAFTER\n' + CommonSystemMethods.sanitizeJSONString(response));

public static String sanitizeJSONString(String jsonString){
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('\n', '');
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll('\t', '');
return jsonString;
}`

Comment: added sample code which throws same error, I'm testing this on eclipse currently

Comment: any standard way instead of `replaceAll('\t', '')`? that's is not good and risky to miss something