# JSON Unexpected character ('P' (code 80))

Tags: apex, visualforce, json, angularjs

I'm working with JSON and I got this error when the page deserializes it:

> Unexpected character ('P' (code 80)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:4074]

I write you the steps that I did for pass the information with JSON:

- In the class I serialize the information with: `json = System.JSON.serialize(lstWrap);`
- Then I store the json in an angularjs variable: `$scope.items ={!prf};`
- After I perform some action on the items I update the variable `json` with

  ```
  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
      <apex:commandButton value="Seleziona" action="{!seleziona}" reRender="ric,prova" >
          <apex:param name="json" value="{{items}}" assignTo="{!json}"/>
      </apex:commandButton>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  ```
- Finally I deserialize the json:

  ```
  List<ProdCheckWrapper> listWrap = (List<ProdCheckWrapper>)System.JSON.deserialize(json,List<ProdCheckWrapper>.class);
  ```

I reported the steps because the issue could be in there.
The problem in json is in this part:

```
"descr":" "PEC" (Elaide e AliasLab)"
```

Instead of, as it is at the start of execution:

```
"descr":" \"PEC\" (Elaide e AliasLab)"
```

In fact http://jsonlint.com/ says:

> Parse error on line 239: ...ronica certificata "PEC" (Elaide e Alias
>   -----------------------^ Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']

I'll try to replace the " with \" but it looks like if the string is immutable.

Comment: Please paste the JSON string .We need to correct the JSON syntax first

Comment: This is the serialized string, BEFORE update: {"productCode":null,"name":"Licenze-OSB","id":"01ta0000001HfAeAAK","family":"Licenze","descr":"Licenze Oracle Service Bus","check":false},{"productCode":null,"name":"Licenze-Pec/Firma Digitale","id":"01ta0000004AMNFAA4","family":"Licenze","descr":"Canone di manutenzione per vendita della piattaforma di Firma Digitale e posta elttronica certificata \"PEC\" (Elaide e AliasLab)","check":false}

Comment: After update it looks like this: {"productCode":null,"name":"Licenze-Pec/Firma Digitale","id":"01ta0000004AMNFAA4","family":"Licenze","descr":"Canone di manutenzione per vendita della piattaforma di Firma Digitale e posta elttronica certificata "PEC" (Elaide e AliasLab)","check":false}

Comment: Thats the problem .After update you have no more valid JSON there .There must be some angular method to preserve \ in the JSON .

Comment: any ideas on how preserves the \?

Comment: Have you done an "Inspect Element" on the rendered page near the "Seleziona" button to check what is going on? I'd be surprised if your combination of server-side and client-side logic plays together well...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an answer on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28105/json-and-escaped-double-quote) although it does not provide the code... that basically you need to escape the escape character. They don't provide any code, and it's not exactly clear where that would happen in your code...